# Need separate error handler for each module in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using zend framework 2 for API. The folder structure is as follows

- Project

  - Config
  - Module

    - Api

      - Module.php
    - Apiv2

      - Module.php

The code in module.php in both modules as below :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR,array($this, 'handleError'));
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR,array($this, 'handleError'));
}

public function handleError(MvcEvent $evt)
{
    //this is to force the error handleing so that our responses are also correct and 
    $router = $evt->getRouter();
    $uriString = $router->getRequestUri();
    $uri = new Uri($uriString);
    $queryArr = $uri->getQueryAsArray();

    $js = new JsonModel();
    $exception = $evt->getParam('exception');
    if(!$exception){

        $valueToEncode = array(
                'errorcode'=>"1",
                'message' =>$evt->getError(),
                'statuscode'=>404,
                'file'=>$evt->getName(),
                'line'=>0
        );
    }
    else{
        ....
    }
}
```

I want different code in handleError method of Apiv2 module than the code in Api module. But The code conflicts for both modules.

Please give me solution so that each module's error handler method should work separately.

Comment: Where does it conflict? Also why would you be using zend framework for an API? That is an overkill use something a minimal framework like Slim for that.

Comment: @Andre, The issue is resolved. I added if condition in module.php to call the appropriate error handler according to the module called. Thanks.